# Error during kivy installation on Windows 10

Tags: installation, kivy

When I try to install kivy to my computer I get the follow error: 
`Error executing cmd /u /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x86 && set`

Screen with the error as shown below.
[image]